# Detect if user is Page administrator with FB JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a Facebook app, added it to a Facebook Fan page and I want to detect whether the user visiting the app tab is an administrator of the actual Fan Page (not the app). Is this possible through FB's JS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has authorised your app and you have the `manage_pages` permission from them, yes.
Otherwise, no, you'll need to do this server side by parsing the `signed_request`

Comment: Parsed the signed_request in PHP. Thanks!